# how to connect a ruby TCP server through a node net socket?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sockets, node.js, tcp

this is my ruby server:

```
require "socket"

server=TCPServer.open(2000)

loop{
    puts "wait for connect"
    client=server.accept
    puts "connect"
    client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
    client.close
}
```

and i writed a ruby client which is work fine:

```
require "socket"
s=TCPSocket.open("localhost",2000)

while line=s.gets
    puts line.chop
end

s.close
```

but when i want to use a node socket instead, i got `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`.

this is my node code:

```
var client, net;
net = require("net");
client = net.createConnection(2000);
console.log("connected");
client.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
client.on("end", function () {
    return console.log("client closed");
});
```

is something wrong i had done?

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -anp | grep 2000` ?

Comment: Is your server no longer running?

Comment: no, the ruby `client` always work fine.

Comment: The output from `netstat` indicates that the server is not running, and the error is also one that you get when the server you try to connect to is not running. Your `node.js` code above works for me when I run the server in one terminal window and the client in another.

Comment: thanks to all.i have fixed this problem by assigning my real IP adress.but i want to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a port twice, if you run a server, you can't connect to localhost on that port.